# Fallo al Reconectar Mysql en NodeJS

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express

Buenos días tengo el siguiente servicio para manejar las conexiones a mysql

```js
var mysqlService = require( 'mysql' );
import { config } from '../../config';

var connection;
function handleDisconnect() {
  connection = mysqlService.createConnection( config ); // Recreate the connection, since
  // the old one cannot be reused.

  connection.connect( function ( err ) {              // The server is either down
    if ( err ) {                                     // or restarting (takes a while sometimes).
      console.log( 'error when connecting to db:', err );
      setTimeout( handleDisconnect, 2000 ); // We introduce a delay before attempting to reconnect,
    } else {
      console.log( "Connected To Mysql" );
    }                                     // to avoid a hot loop, and to allow our node script to
  });                                     // process asynchronous requests in the meantime.
  // If you're also serving http, display a 503 error.
  connection.on( 'error', function ( err ) {
    console.log( 'db error', err );
    if ( err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST' ) { // Connection to the MySQL server is usually
      handleDisconnect();                         // lost due to either server restart, or a
    } else {                                      // connnection idle timeout (the wait_timeout
      throw err;                                  // server variable configures this)
    }
  });
}

handleDisconnect();
export const mysql = connection;
```

El problema es que cuándo la conexión de pierde la nueva conexión no me permite ejecutar queries y me devuelve el error:
Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.

Pareciera como si siguiera apuntando a la conexión anterior y no a la nueva.
Existe un error en mi forma de exportar la conexión para poder reutilizarla?

Answer (score 1):

He logrado solucionar mi problema creando un pool de mysql:

```js
var mysqlService = require( 'mysql' );
import {  config } from '../../config';

var pool = mysqlService.createPool( config );

export const queryExecute = ( sql, params, callback ) => {
  pool.getConnection( function ( err, connection ) {
    if ( err ) {
      console.log( err );
      callback( true );
      return;
    }
    connection.query( sql, params, function ( err, results, fields ) {
      connection.release(); // always put connection back in pool after last query
      callback( err, results, fields );
    });
  });
};
```